# Are there guidelines to the 'Alphabet Soup' of Statistics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimators

This is a somewhat 'meta-statistical' question that pertains to the discipline of Statistics, rather than to Statistics itself. I will not be accepting any answers due to the subject being open-ended. It really is open-ended, and therefore will possibly be closed, but it is quite relevant to the practice of Statistics.

There is a frequent pattern of statistical estimators (or hypothesis tests) in following a naming convention of `<PERSON NAME> <LETTER>`. Most of us probably name a few off the top of our heads including:

- [Bangdiwala's B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangdiwala%27s_B)
- [Box's M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%27s_M_test)
- [Cohen's $\kappa$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)
- [Cramér's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)
- [Somers' D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somers%27_D)
- [Cochran's Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test)
- [Cochran's C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_C_test)
- [Pearson's r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)
- [Pearson's $\chi^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)
- [Spearman's $\rho$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)
- [Kendall's $\tau$-(a/b)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient)
- [Mann-Whitney U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)
- [Goodman and Kruskal's $\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_gamma)
- [Goodman and Kruskal's $\lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_lambda)
- [Yule's Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_colligation)
- [Hotelling's T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution#Two-sample_statistic)
- [Kendall's W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_W)
- [Student's $t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)
- [Cronbach's $\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha)

There are also statistcs with just a single letter:

- [$\chi^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test)
- [F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test)
- [$\phi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient)
- [Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test)

And there are statistics that are just the (possibly hyphenated) names of people:

- [Brown-Forsythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%E2%80%93Forsythe_test)
- [Brunner-Munzel](https://www.statisticshowto.com/brunner-munzel-test-generalized-wilcoxon-test/)
- [Levene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test)
- [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)
- [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test)
- [D'Agostino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Agostino%27s_K-squared_test)
- [Anderson-Darling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test)
- [Dickey-Fuller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test)
- [Kruskal-Wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance)
- [Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPSS_test)
- [Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test)
- [Durbin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin_test)
- [Durbin-Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic)
- [Durbin-Wu-Hausman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Wu%E2%80%93Hausman_test)
- [Wilcoxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test)
- [Matthews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)
- [Bartlett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test)
- [Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley%27s_test)
- [Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser_Meyer_Olkin_test)
- [Breusch-Godfrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Godfrey_test)
- [Breusch-Pagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test)
- [Ljung-Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test)
- [Wald-Wolfowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test)
- [Wald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test)
- [Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics)
- [Chow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test)
- [Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test)
- [Mantel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel_test)
- [Sorensen-Dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient)
- [Renkonen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renkonen_similarity_index)
- [Tversky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tversky_index)
- [Bray-Curtis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bray%E2%80%93Curtis_dissimilarity)
- [Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)
- [Jarque-Bera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test)
- [Akaike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)
- [Gershunov](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/clim/14/11/1520-0442_2001_014_2486_lfmote_2.0.co_2.xml)
- [Mann-Kendall](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/feart.2020.00014/full)

It seems that some statistics such as [U-statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-statistic), [V-Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-statistic), [L-Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-estimator), and [Q-Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-statistic) may inspire/generate naming patterns. But on the whole, the names seem to follow the idiosyncrasies of history.

If I were to publish a new statistical estimator, what considerations would I put into naming it?

Comment: Most of the time *other* authors than those named were the ones that coined the expression. Spending too much time thinking about generic naming schemes is, in my opinion, a near-complete waste of time.

Comment: Call it whatever you want, there are no rules for naming estimators. If there was a single-letter rule, we would soon deploy the pool of possible names--then what? Moreover, you *don't* really need to name it.

Comment: I would guess that most, maybe all, of these got their common names from people other than their namesakes.

Comment: Yes @Dave , [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy) applies to at least some of them.

Comment: _If I were to publish a new statistical estimator, what considerations would I put into naming it?_ Easy advice: Don't name after yourself (easy not to do). Choose a symbol that isn't in heavy use elsewhere (much harder).

Comment: It's time to stop editing this post.

Comment: @whuber Why? Under what policy should I stop editing this post?

Comment: It's a combination of the "stop annoying us" and "please don't game the system" policies.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.

Comment: @whuber I have read [https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) and it recommends putting a bounty on unanswered questions.

Comment: I am not able to put [a bounty](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on this question. This is probably due to it being closed at this moment.

Comment: I am interested in creating a post that provides value, and I see these edits as small improvements. It is not my intent to annoy anyone, nor to somehow 'game the system'. I can however edit less frequently since it is felt by some that I have edited too much.

Comment: "Pearson's $r$" is a sample statistic estimating Pearson's $\rho$. Spearman's $r$ (aka $r_{\text{S}}$ is a sample statistic estimating Spearman's $\rho$ (which is Pearson's $\rho$ on ranked data).

Comment: I agree with you @Alexis, which leads to a point that there is a convention that the English letters (which stem from Latin) should be used for estimators and the corresponding Greek letters should be used for population parameters. I don't think this convention is always followed, but it is something worth considering. Thank you.

Comment: The bounty block is a feature. There's an intended order to this: first the reasons for the closure have to be addressed. Making many tiny edits in a short period works against you because people get used to seeing the thread pop back to the top of the question queue and start ignoring it. (In egregious cases the reaction is to begin downvoting.) // Certainly we appreciate attention to detail and improvement of questions.  But there are diminishing returns and they are reached long before 20 edits.  Indeed, that much editing is characteristic of long lists--and such posts don't fit our format.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your perspective, @whuber.